# How can I print a list which is in another list? (scala)

Tags: scala, list

I have the following code:

```
var sessionIds = List[Int](12345,54321)
var Frames = List[(String, String, String, String)](("Music","Duration","Distance","Whatever"))
var someMoreFrames = List[(Int, Int, String)](1,2,"hello"))

  //Do some other stuff here

var returnValue = List[(List[Int], List[(String, String, String, String)], List[(Int, Int, String)])]((sessionIds,Frames,someMoreFrames))
```

Now I want to print the list returnValue and I want the following output:

```
12345
54321
(Music,Duration,Distance,Whatever)
(1,2,hello)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the print as you want, you can try this:

```
returnValue.foreach { x =>
  println(x._1.foreach(println) + "\n" +
    x._2.foreach(println)+ "\n" +
    x._3.foreach(println))
}
```

It will give you output as you want:

```
12345
54321
(Music,Duration,Distance,Whatever)
(1,2,hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var sessionIds = List[Int](12345,54321)
var Frames = List[(String, String, String, String)](("Music","Duration","Distance","Whatever"))
var someMoreFrames = List[(Int, Int, String)]((1,2,"hello"))

val returnValue = sessionIds ++ Frames ++ someMoreFrames
returnValue.foreach(line => println(line))
```